# Content Query Crazy behavior

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, https

I have a custom webpart that works like a carrousel, just showing images... im having problems because when the site is acessed via https the images just dont show...

the images are not hardcoded, they're on the a style lib and im fetching the list and then getting the link via

```
item["Encoded Absolute URL"].ToString()
```

but no matter what, the link to the images are always "http"... can anyone help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to the way the site is published and how the alternate access mappings are setup, could be that if you've got TMG server inplace it might be setup to do 443 -> 80 and do link translation which means the URL is being interprted on the SharePoint server as if it was seeing the request come from the local TMG server.